# How to config CLOVER for PC for UEFI Systems

Tags: operating-system, clover

I have done this here: [Clover for PCs](https://www.aioboot.com/en/clover-bootloader-windows/) and now I would like to know

1. need the Legacy EXE Program to be run even when UEFI is used and I would like to integrate legacy BIOS AND UEFI.
2. How can I config the CLOVER and its list when I have a ISO File for the PC, which should be started after seleced in CLOVER.

Thanks